# input values are getting cleared for few times on click of command button

Tags: jsf, tomcat, jsf-2

Even if I input the values, on click of command button the values are getting cleared only for few times not at all time. We are using tomcat 8 web server.

Reason is unknown why this is happening.
Could not track the issue as it occurred for few times not happening all times.

We are guessing that problem is getting slow response in flow (i.e. Browser -> Apache -> Tomcat -> Oracle). But where exactly not known.

Any suggestions please...

Comment: Are you (ab)using the `enableRestoreView11Compatibility` setting? That's one of most common causes for this behavior.

Comment: @BalusC..thanks for the reply. We are not using any `enableRestoreView11Compatibility` setting.

Comment: You may create automated tests by using Selenium and hopefully recreate the error.